# FileProvider.getUriForFile: check for authority used

Tags: android

I am using a simple method to capture an Image from Camera but I get the error reported below at this point:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ReceiptActivity.this, "com.example.ves.gennaio3.fileprovider", pictureFile);
```

According to me, it is related to the authority used, but it seems correct in the Manifest.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider
 android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
 android:authorities="com.example.ves.gennaio3.fileprovider"
 android:exported="false"
 android:grantUriPermissions="true"
 android:readPermission="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ">
 <meta-data
  android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
  android:resource="@xml/file_list" />
</provider>
```

**res/xml/file_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="my_images" />
</paths>
```

**Java**

```
public void captureImage(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        pictureFile = Helper.getPictureFile(ReceiptActivity.this);
        if (pictureFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ReceiptActivity.this, "com.example.ves.gennaio3.fileprovider", pictureFile); //error here
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
> 04-23 17:44:38.456 27102-27102/com.example.ves.gennaio3
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.ves.gennaio3, PID: 27102
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.ves.gennaio3/files/Pictures/OCR_20190423174438-702062338.jpg
>         at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:738)
>         at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
>         at com.example.ves.gennaio3.ReceiptActivity.captureImage(ReceiptActivity.java:173)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201) 
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

PS. I have tried to make a slim question but it looks like that my post is mostly code, so I am adding other unuseful text just to make it postable.

Comment: It's not the authority. You've apparently not specified an appropriate path for that file location in your `file_list` XML.

Comment: thanks @MikeM. I have already read the question you talk about but it doesn't seem that the issue is XML file. Just to be sure, I have added it to this question.

Comment: That `path` isn't valid for your file path. If anything, you'd want `path="Pictures"`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, someone incorrectly edited CommonsWare's answer there. I'm not sure why he approved that edit. Probably just a simple oversight. I'll throw him a comment about it.